# Первое вхождение символа(совпадение). Java. Регулярные выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, в чем проблема?

```
  Pattern patternDate = Pattern.compile("(?<=Опубликован:)(.*)(?=\\|)");
                Matcher matcherDate = patternDate.matcher("04.03.2017 | 20:13 [последние изменения: 04.03.2017 | 20:14]");
                while (matcherDate.find()) {
                    System.out.println(matcherDate.group());

                }
```

Я получаю ***04.03.2017 | 20:13 [последние изменения: 04.03.2017***

а мне нужно **04.03.2017**

Comment: Используйте захватывающую группу и исключающий символьный класс - `"Опубликован:\\s*([^|]+)"` -> `if (matcherDate.find()) {
                    System.out.println(matcherDate.group(1));}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте не жадное сравнение. Для этого после `*` поставьте `?`

```
Pattern patternDate = Pattern.compile("(?<=Опубликован:)(.*?)(?=\\|)")
```